# Like facebook page when login with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using facebook login on my webpage.
At first login the facebook login app ask for permission to get user data.

There is any way to improve this to ask for permission of liking my facebook page too?
And after user clicks, he would also like my facebook page.

Edit:
My goal is to force people to like my facebook page if they want to login with facebook account to my page (not regular registration). For sure I would ask for permission to not violate terms of use. But would be nice if when they click on login and giving permission they would also like my fb page. So Facebook login and like wouldn't be seperated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you've just add the scope **user_likes** to the facebook login button.

You can read more about the facebook login button and the scope attribute [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)

Now that you can access to the user likes, you can check if the user likes your page, if so, great just redirect the user to your website, if not, just prompt him to like your page before he can access the rest of your website.

here's some code, using Facebook Javascript SDK

```html
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', like);
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Then on the bottom of the page, put this piece of javascript code

```html
<script>
    //this function is fired whenever the user presses the like button
    function like(response) {    
        if(response="https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_USERNAME")
            //do something when the user likes your page, like redirect him, or something like that
    }
    //this function is fired everytime the page is loaded
    function handleStatusChange(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            updateUserInfo(response);
        }
    }
    //this function is called by the function handleStatusChange and it checks everytime the page is loaded if the user already likes your page
    function updateUserInfo(response) {
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me/likes/YOUR_PAGE_ID', function(response) {
            if(response.data.length){
             //the user already likes your page 
            }
            else{
                //the user doesn'y like your page, or the user hasn't granted permission for you to access his likes. show him the like button
            }
        }, {access_token: token});

   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)? If so, can you explain why it does not suit your needs?

Comment: Thank you four your reply, I edited my question to be more understandable but my english quite bad.
So, this not suit my needs because I want "login with facebook" and like my fb page not be seperated